# No muestra la imagen alojada en la base de datos SQL Server

Tags: php

aqui yo de nuevo. Resulta que estoy buscando como mostrar una imagen alojada en la base de datos. Intenté decodificando la versión en base64 y me lo mostraba entrecortado, ahorita estaba buscando cómo hacerlo mediante blob y no me muestra nada. Acá mando los códigos y cómo se guardan en la base de datos (el servidor que ocupo en el trabajo no toma el driver sqlsrv por lo que tuve que usar uno que ya está obsoleto).

blob.php:

```
<?php 
include 'src/functions/dbfunctions.php';
    $conn = connectDB();
    $id = $_GET['id'];

if ($id > 0){
    //vamos a crear nuestra consulta SQL
    $query = "SELECT imagen_GXI from formulario WHERE formularioId = '$id'"; 
    //con mysql_query la ejecutamos en nuestra base de datos indicada anteriormente
    //de lo contrario mostraremos el error que ocaciono la consulta y detendremos la ejecucion.
    $resultado= mssql_query($query, $conn) or die(mssql_error());

    //si el resultado fue exitoso
    //obtendremos el dato que ha devuelto la base de datos
    $datos = mssql_fetch_assoc($resultado);

    //ruta va a obtener un valor parecido a "imagenes/nombre_imagen.jpg" por ejemplo
    $imagen = $datos['imagen_GXI'];

    //ahora colocamos la cabeceras correcta segun el tipo de imagen
    header("Content-type: image/jpeg");

    echo $imagen;
}
?>
```

Como muestro la imagen en modvegetales.php

```
<img src="blob.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>" />
```

Asi se guardan en la base de datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Y esto se muestra en blob.php segun la id:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cualquier ayuda o sugerencia estoy agradecido. Gracias!

Comment: No termino de comprender. ¿Lo que se guarda en el campo `imagen` es la imagen codificada en base64 o blob? ¿Y qué es lo que se guarda en `imagen_GXI`, el nombre de la imagen solamente o la ubicación física de la imagen en el servidor?

Comment: Lo que se guarda en el campo `imagen` efectivamente está codificada en base64. Ahora revisando el diseño de la tabla el tipo de datos es VARBINARY. Y en `imagen_GXI` se supone que está la ubicación de la imagen en el servidor.